# How do I return an int from EditText? (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Basically, I want an EditText in Android where I can have an integer value entered into. Perhaps there is a more appropriate object than EditText for this?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

For now, use an `EditText`. Use `android:inputType="number"` to force it to be numeric. Convert the resulting string into an integer (e.g., `Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString())`).

In the future, you might consider a `NumberPicker` widget, once that becomes available (slated to be in Honeycomb).

Comment: Offhand, in Java, do you know what is the integer equivalent of the "number" inputType android attribute? (ie: EditText.setInputType(integer)). Thanks.

Comment: @Rob S.: `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`, as indicated in the documentation.

Comment: I think this should be expanded to account for cases when the editText has no value (i.e. editText.getText() == "").

Comment: Exception is raised when the edittext is null.When giving like Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString())

Answer (score 12):

Set the [digits](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adigits) attribute to true, which will cause it to only allow number inputs.

Then do `Integer.valueOf(editText.getText())` to get an int value out.

Comment: won't this cause `The method valueOf(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Editable)` error?

Comment: @zhangxaochen - `getText()` is not String. It is needed to call `getText().toString()`

Answer (score 9):

First of all get a string from an EDITTEXT and then convert this string into integer like

```
      String no=myTxt.getText().toString();       //this will get a string                               
      int no2=Integer.parseInt(no);              //this will get a no from the string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in 2 steps:

1: Change the input type(In your `EditText` field) in the layout file to `android:inputType="number"`

2: Use `int a = Integer.parseInt(yourEditTextObject.getText().toString());`

Comment: As other answers have pointed out, though, it's really more of an "and" than an "or", right? If you do 1, then you still need to do 2, the XML can't alter what you get as a return type in Java, and if you do 2, then you'll want to do 1 to ensure safe input. You'll always need to do 2 and it's best to just do both.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it was a typo!

Comment: (to put those comments in context, the issue has since been fixed via edit)