# passing parameters via intent to a query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I need to pass a parameter from an EditText and when I click the button, it'll start another activity and get that parameter and pass it to a query. It follows:

```
final Button ara = (Button) findViewById(R.id.maddebutton);
    ara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String maddeno = madde.getText().toString(); //madde is my EditText
            Intent intent = new Intent(Anayasa.this, MaddeBul.class);
            intent.putExtra("maddeler", maddeno);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
```

my second class is as follows:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    int maddebul = intent.getIntExtra("maddeler", 0); //I don't want to set a default value but it pushes me

try {
        Cursor cursor = FetchRecord(db.query("anayasa", SELECT,
                "no = maddebul", null, null, null, null));
        ShowRecord(cursor);
    } finally {
        database.close();
    }
```

my `FetchRecord(Cursor c)` and `ShowRecord(Cursor cursor)` functions work fine, since I'm using them in other classes. There is "no" column in my "anayasa" database which holds integer values.

On LogCat, it says "no column such maddebul". It is true, there isn't. It suppose to be:

```
SELECT * FROM anayasa WHERE no = maddebul; //as sql command
```

Any help?

Comment: why are you using getIntExtra for a string?

Comment: I wasn't. I was trying different things I forgot it as you have said. I'm editting my question. I cannot edit now :)

String maddeno = madde.getText().toString(); will be 

Editable maddeno = madde.getText();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

You put `maddebul` as String here so need to get it like this:

```
String maddebul = intent.getStringExtra("maddeler", "");
```

Also you are forming your SQL query wrong, `maddebul` is passed as a String to the db, whereas you actually want to pass the value of that variable. So it could be like this instead:

```
Cursor cursor = FetchRecord(db.query("anayasa", SELECT,
                "no = ?",new String[]{maddebul}, null, null, null));
```

Comment: excellent explanation. As all of you said, I used my sql wrong. eyvallah :)

Answer (score 2):

You are adding your extra as a String here:

```
intent.putExtra("maddeler", maddeno);
```

But when you try to retrieve the extra you are retrieving it as an int:

```
int maddebul = intent.getIntExtra("maddeler", 0);
```

Try using this insteald

```
String maddebul = intent.getStringExtra("maddeler", "");
```

For reference here are the docs for the [getStringExtra() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
On LogCat, it says "no column such maddebul". It is true, there isn't.
```

due to in whereClause "no = maddebul",  maddebul is not a variable it is string part so change the whereClause to take it's value

```
Cursor cursor = FetchRecord(db.query("anayasa", SELECT,
                    "no = maddebul", null, null, null, null));
```

should be

```
Cursor cursor = FetchRecord(db.query("anayasa", SELECT,
                "no = "+maddebul, null, null, null, null));
```

Comment: I thought I should use WHERE clause as I used. Therefore I put maddebul in "". thanks

Comment: how can I get my EditText value as int? EditText only gets integers by the way.


I found my answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/4903531/1443879

Answer (score 0):

you are writing maddebul in Double Quotes.

Replace

```
Cursor cursor = FetchRecord(db.query("anayasa", SELECT,
                "no = maddebul", null, null, null, null));
```

By

```
Cursor cursor = FetchRecord(db.query("anayasa", SELECT,
                "no = "+maddebul, null, null, null, null));
```

Better use following

```
Cursor cursor = FetchRecord(db.query("anayasa", SELECT,
                "no = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(maddebul)}, null, null, null));
```

Comment: I don't get "better use following" part. what is "no = ?"

Also, it is related to selectionArgs, right? new String[]{ String.valueOf(maddebul)} should refer me my variable which is '?' in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You are put Extra as String and geting it as Integer - maybe that's the problem?

Comment: By the way, can I putExtra as integer? When I try, Eclipse doesn't let me and makes me change it as Editable.