# Converting EditText to int? (Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext, integer

I am wondering how to convert an `EditText` input to an int, I have the user input a number, which then divides it by 8.

MainActivity.java:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void calcSpeed(View view)
{       
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_speed);     
    
    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    mTextView.setText("You should be getting: " +netSpedCalcd);
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1" 
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:ems="10" >
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903515/how-do-i-return-an-int-from-edittext-android

Answer (score 54):

you have to used.

```
String value= et.getText().toString();
int finalValue=Integer.parseInt(value);
```

if you have only allow enter number then set EditText property.

```
android:inputType="number"
```

if this is helpful then accept otherwise put your comment.

Comment: EditText et =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ettext);   like this.

Comment: EditText et =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);   
  int nIntFromET = Integer.parseInt(text);



It says "text cannot be resolved to a variable"

Answer (score 10):

Use [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), and make sure you catch the NumberFormatException that it throws if the input is not an integer.

Answer (score 9):

I'm very sleepy and tired right now but wouldn't this work?:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String sTextFromET = et.getText().toString();
int nIntFromET = new Integer(sTextFromET).intValue();
```

***OR***

```
try
{
    int nIntFromET = Integer.parseInt(sTextFromET);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    // handle the exception
}
```

Comment: For the first one, it said "et cannot be resolved"                                                    For the second, it said "Integer.parseInt cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: I've edited the answer (awaiting peer review), but the problem with the second case is the spurious "new", just remove that.

Comment: Alright, for the sTextFromET, it says "sTextFromET cannot be resolved to a variable", what do I do? (Sorry, I'm new to Java and programming in general.)

Comment: Replace sTextFromET with a call to getText() on the EditText instance that you are trying to get the value from.

Comment: I have tried the following that I have found on different stackoverflow questions, and I get a NullPointerException.                 

http://pastebin.com/LaXYb4LC

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
EditText x = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
int n = Integer.parseInt(x.getText().toString());
```

Comment: [Guaranteed to not work](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#toString()). The link is a hint.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use parseInt with try and catch block**

```
try
{
    int myVal= Integer.parseInt(mTextView.getText().toString());
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    // handle the exception
    int myVal=0;
}
```

**Or you can create your own tryParse method :**

```
public Integer tryParse(Object obj) {
    Integer retVal;
    try {
        retVal = Integer.parseInt((String) obj);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        retVal = 0; // or null if that is your preference
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

**and use it in your code like:**

```
int myVal= tryParse(mTextView.getText().toString());
```

---

**Note: The following code without try/catch will throw an exception**

```
int myVal= new Integer(mTextView.getText().toString()).intValue();
```

Or

```
int myVal= Integer.decode(mTextView.getText().toString()).intValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the line below to convert editText to integer.

```
int intVal = Integer.parseInt(mEtValue.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem myself. I'm not sure if you got it to work though, but what I had to was:

```
EditText cypherInput;
cypherInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_cipherValue);
int cypher = Integer.parseInt(cypherInput.getText().toString());
```

The third line of code caused the app to crash without using the .getText() before the .toString().

Just for reference, here is my XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_cipherValue"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
 EditText dollar=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.money);
 int rupees=Integer.parseInt( dollar.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

First, find your `EditText` in the resource of the android studio by using this code:

`EditText value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

Then convert `EditText` value into a `string` and then parse the value to an `int`.

`int number = Integer.parseInt(x.getText().toString());`

This will work

Answer (score 0):

```
int total_Parson = Integer.parseInt(etRegularTickets.getText().toString());
int ticket_price=Integer.parseInt(TicketData.get(0).getTicket_price_regular());
total_ticket_amount = ticket_price * total_Parson;
etRegularPrice.setText(""+total_ticket_amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, you can do this.

```
val editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText)
val intNum = editText1.text.toString().toInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, there is shortest way thanks to the **Extension Function**

```
fun EditText.toInt(): Int {
    return this.text.toString().toInt()
}
```

Use it in your code like below:

```
mEditText.toInt()
```