# Android Studio convert alertdialog edittext to int

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm making a game in which the player enters a number in an `AlertDialog` box, and I need to use this input as an `int` variable. How can I get it?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final EditText input = new EditText(this); //the number
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
builder.setView(input);
builder.setTitle("Begin Game");
builder.setMessage("How Many rounds do you want?");
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new HandleAlertDialogListener());
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting EditText to int? (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037465/converting-edittext-to-int-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an `int` back by parsing the `input`'s text :

```
 final int rounds = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
```

Note [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) throws a `NumberFormatException` when it can't parse a number.

Comment: it gives me an error when i try to run the app when i add this line.

Comment: @Pecktos By "describing" an error, I mean providing **all** output related to it, e.g. Android Logcat entries.