# Incompatible types: android.widget.EditText and java.lang.Integer

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

What can be done with the editMobile_Number value to pass it as an Integer parameter?

I had tried  myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(editMobile_Number.getText().toString()));  This results to terminating the App abruptly.
Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return an int from EditText? (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903515/how-do-i-return-an-int-from-edittext-android)

Comment: Please post the logcat errors at the time the app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing .toString() from the code below:

```
Integer.parseInt(editMobile_Number.getText().toString()));//remove .toString().
```